# How can I handle 503 errors with open-uri?

Tags: ruby, error-handling, open-uri

If a website returns a '503 service unavailable' error then open-uri throws an exception. For example:

```
require 'open-uri'
open('http://www.google.co.uk/sorry/?continue=http://www.google.co.uk/search%3Fq%3Dhello%26oq%3Dhello%26ie%3DUTF-8')
# OpenURI::HTTPError: 503 Service Unavailable
# ...
```

However if you then visit it in a web browser, it actually displays a page with a CAPTCHA and not an error.

How can I make sure open-uri doesn't just throw this as an exception but actually handles the response and provides me with the page content?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

`OpenURI::HTTPError` have an `io` attribute you can inspect to get what you want. `io` is a `StringIO` object with several singleton methods defined on it (`status` for example):

```
require 'open-uri'
begin
  open('http://www.google.co.uk/sorry/?continue=http://www.google.co.uk/search%3Fq%3Dhello%26oq%3Dhello%26ie%3DUTF-8')
rescue OpenURI::HTTPError => error
  response = error.io
  response.status
  # => ["503", "Service Unavailable"] 
  response.string
  # => <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN\">\n<html DIR=\"LTR\">\n<head><meta http-equiv=\"content-type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\"><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"initial-scale=1\">...
end
```

However for this task the `Net::HTTP` module is probably a better alternative:

```
require 'net/http'
response = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse('http://www.google.co.uk/sorry/?continue=http://www.google.co.uk/search%3Fq%3Dhello%26oq%3Dhello%26ie%3DUTF-8'))
response.code
# => "503"
response.body
# => "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN\">\n<html DIR=\"LTR\">\n<head><meta http-equiv=\"content-type\" content=\"text/html; ...
```

Comment: Thank you! I read your answer to the question before you edited it, I was reading about exceptions and that they shouldn't be used for common conditions. So would it be better to use net/http instead of open-uri as it means I don't have to use one?